How can I identify the Illumina genotyping array probe-category?
background:
I am working with genotyping data from the Infinium™ Global Screening Array-24 v3.0 BeadChip and already have access to the VCF files. I want to determine if there is a reference or categorical breakdown of the probes (e.g., ancestry informative markers, clinical markers, etc.).
I have reviewed the following resources from Illumina:

Info sheet
Product files
Support files
General product documentation

The information sheet mentions various probe categories, including a breakdown of the number of probes in each category. For example:

AIMs: 2,923 Ancestry-informative markers (b. Based on internal calculations).

However, I have been unable to locate a clear reference or manifest that maps these categories to their specific probe IDs or genomic positions.

My Questions:

Does Illumina provide a categorical reference sheet that explicitly maps probe IDs (e.g., rsIDs) to functional groups, such as:

AIMs (Ancestry Informative Markers)
Clinical markers
Other functional categories?


Are there standard tools or resources to cross-reference probe IDs or genomic positions with their functional annotations?


Any guidance or resources for identifying and categorizing these probes would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
